How am I misusing in_array?
Consider the following PHP:
<?php
if (in_array('cookie_name', $_GET, false)) {
    echo "Found";
}
var_dump($_GET);
echo $_GET['cookie_name'] . "\n";
?>

If I put this on a webserver and use curl with cookie_name=xxx, I get the following output, which does not include the string Found.
array(1) {
  ["cookie_name"]=>
  string(3) "xxx"
}
xxx

I feel that I must be using in_array incorrectly but I do not see how.
Any hints?

in_array checks for values, not keys. You want array_key_exists, or simply isset.

You should do isset($_GET['cookie_name']) instead of in_array

Ah, that was it! Thanks both of you, and sorry I read the docs and totally brain farted and treated the associative array like a Python dictionary, and in_array as being having semantics of key in {}.
